# Speaker enclosures

Tags: speakers

I'm just about to embark on making a cabinet for two 12" speakers (and possibly bullet) for use with guitar.

Some cabs are totally enclosed, some have open backs, and I've built some with a port at the front. Albeit not with a pair of Celestion 12" speakers, which may/not have a bearing.

Not sure what the actual sonic differences are - which would suit a decent sized amp for the purposes of gigging, for what reasons?

Comment: Wouldn't this question is better suited for [Sound Design SE](https://sound.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @ElementsinSpace That was my first thought too, but reading their on-topic descriptions, I’m not sure they’re so interested in gear either

Comment: In this context, what is a "bullet"? Is that UK English for tweeter?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - it's a particular design of tweeter. Example - https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyp7F.jpg You do see the bullet centre in other, standard speaker types, but this design is the 'classic'.

Answer (score 5):

Open back actually *sounds* more open. They fill a small stage, so you and the band can hear what's going on without need for on-stage monitoring so much.
Downside, front of house can have more trouble capturing that sound & sending it to the audience. You can get spill in other stage mics. They have less low end & 'punch' in the mids.

Closed back - you got it, more closed - a tighter sound, and more directional. They project forwards, with far less spill. Consequently, if you're not directly in line with it, you don't hear the top so well. Walking round the stage your perception of your own sound will change. Cab designers describe it as 'laser-like'. Front of house will like it too, it spills less.
Overall, sonically, it has more low & more mid 'punch'. You could consider it more 'contained' in all senses of the word.

Some cab manufacturers who seem to agree -
[Roland - Open Back Vs Closed Back Guitar Speaker Cabinets – What’s The Difference?](https://www.roland.com/uk/blog/open-back-vs-closed-back-amp/)
[Laney - Open Back vs Closed Back Cabinets – Do Cabs Make A Difference?](https://www.laney.co.uk/blog/open-back-vs-closed-back-cabinets-do-cabs-make-a-difference/)
[Celestion - Open Back or Closed Back Cabinet – Which is for Me?](https://celestion.com/blog/open-back-or-closed-back-cabinet-which-is-for-me/)
[Fender - What's The Difference Between Open-Back And Closed-Back Speaker Enclosures?](https://www.fender.com/articles/parts-and-accessories/whats-the-difference-between-open-back-and-closed-back-speaker-enclosures)

More opinion than researched fact…
Bullets are highly directional anyway. I don't think the cabinet design has much influence at all.

Ports, on the other hand, are complete voodoo.
I've never used a guitar amp/cab with a port. My home theatre rig has one… makes the walls shake whilst not being able to hear much from the centre of the room.
My old gig rig bass amp was ported - in fact it was a 5ft tall reverse folded twin-port single 15". Perhaps not the wisest move in retrospect, but I was young. On-stage it sounded fine, got just the sound I & the band wanted. In a small gig, however, the very low end barely had chance to form. In a large venue, it nearly pushed the back 6 rows of the audience into the rear wall. It was a beast… an uncontrollable beast.
My current bass rig doesn't so much have a tuned port as a 'slot at the bottom'. There is no actual shaped porting, just a letter-box hole. It does, however have a DI out that you send to the desk, so it really doesn't matter at all that the sound nearfield is a bit 'loose'.

Long & short; I'd avoid ports on DIY-designed cabinets, as even the pros struggle to tune them to all eventualities.

Just for fun, here are pics of that reverse-folded design, as supplied, & with the front grill & panel removed to see how it was loaded. All port, no forward-facing component at all.

[image] [image]

…and my current rig, a pic showing off that 'hole' in the bottom. (This is off the interwebz, mine is in much better condition that this;)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I get that top is far more directional, so what about the bullet? Worth incorporating one, with the crossover, of course, or what?

Comment: A bullet only really has a 'front'. The cab won't significantly affect it at all.

Comment: I've seen a video that says that the best speakers ever are the ones you built yourself…

Comment: Honestly, anyone claiming that, without the millions of dollars of research money the majors have, is just fooling themselves. Clickbait. I once drove past a sign outside an Elvis wedding chapel in Las Vegas. At least it had the temerity to claim "Rated as the best wedding venue in Las Vegas, by the management."

Comment: Walls shaking and nothing heard in the middle of the room sounds a lot like room resonance

Comment: It's a set of standing wave nodes. They're all brick walls so it's not the walls themselves joining in the fun. Nothing you can do about it - unless you want to start bass-trapping your living room. I'm many things but I'm not **that** anorak ;)

Comment: I've ported a couple of my bass cabs - 15" and 18", with the result that the air coming out of the ports is quite noticeable. However, that's mostly on the lower notes, not necessarily at much volume, either. However, this cab will be used primarily for guitar, with much higher pitches involved. Thus the mention of a bullet, for those harmonics. And, as the cab will be *behind* me, I don't see much need for an open back, which would only be advantageous were it in front - not a clever move, I feel.

Comment: Since I thought about this question, I've been very tempted to try plugging my bass amp's port, just to see how much it might tighten it up - but it would be hard to tell at living room volumes, & I'm not gigging these days so it will never get a full test. If the venue was big enough, the heavy lifting would always be done by FoH anyway, so the on-stage sound was never vitally important. These days, most of what I do involves modelling amps monitored over the studio speakers.

Comment: That very thought did occur to me too: make a movable 'paddle', so I could perhaps tune the port to the room?

Comment: The whole problem with ports is they need to reverse the phase of the sound coming from the rear of the speaker - which is frequency-dependent, of course. Just sticking a hole in the cab [like mine mentioned above seems to be, though I've never taken the whole thing apart to really see in detail] isn't really a 'port' it's just a 'hole'.

Comment: Yes, in my earlier ones, I used a tube going nearly to the back, exiting at the front. Guesswork, but it seems effective!

Comment: I think that the first bass cabinet counts as folded horn enclosure, not bass reflex. And yes, horns are difficult to design and damn loud when they work.

Comment: Ports make no sense for guitars because the only reason to port an enclosure is to extend the low end beyond what would be possible for a sealed or open enclosure of the same size. A 2x12 cabinet that is fully sealed or open can easily reproduce 80 Hz, which is the fundamental of the lowest note on a guitar. Even with drop tunings, the downsides of ports outweigh the benefits for guitars. Porting bass cabs is much more common and in those cases the low end extension is more valuable.

Comment: @ojs I agree, the first image looks like a classic folded horn. These also are not ideal for electric guitar because the primary advantage of horn design is power efficiency, i.e., sensitivity. If you want to throw low frequency sound 100+ feet away, folded horn starts to make more sense (although today we do it with arrays and DSP). For a guitar amp that will be miked, good **tone** is much more important than sensitivity, and folded horns are not suited to good guitar tone.

Comment: @ToddWilcox good points, it's claimed to be a bass cab and the big horn enclosures haven't been in fashion for some time now, especially for instrument amps. Which is a pity, because this looked even more awesome in person: http://www.wigwam.fi/pictures/alwari140803_10.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You need a port for somewhere for the air to go. When the low frequency speaker (woofer) moves you want to avoid compressing the air as this like loading the woofer with a spring. If the cabinet is ported - there is a path for this air.

The air at the back of the woofer is moving in the opposite direction to the air in front of the woofer - it wants to be going in the same direction (phase). A port in the front usually has a extra path to reverse the direction, out the back relies on the depth of the cabinet.

Directionality depends on the "effective aperture" of the woofer/cabinet combination and a wider "effective aperture" produces a more directional sound.

Comment: Not strictly true. I've owned three bass cabs in my life. One was entirely sealed, one has a 'hole' in the bottom, the precise internal configuration of which I've never fully investigated; the third was *entirely* port, there was no front-facing component at all, the speaker was rear-loaded. The speaker within it, though, was itself sealed in a casing, leaving only the front face feeding to the ports. See https://carvinaudio.com/blogs/guitar-bass-education/sealed-vs-ported-whats-the-difference

Comment: Not sure you do need somewhere for the air to go. Tens of thousands of speaker cabs have nowhere for this. Rather like a buffer for the speaker cone.

Comment: @tim where does the air go? In a sealed cabinet when the cone moves backward it compresses the air which acts partially as a spring and as compressed air warms up it dissipates some of the mechanical energy from the cone as heat. This isn't turned into sound. Many sealed cabinets have a passive cone that is driven by the pressure changes and although they don't look like they have a vent there is somewhere for this pressure to go. The opposite happens when the woofer cone moves forward the air still acts as a spring.

Comment: The air goes nowhere. As you state, when the cone goes backwards, it's compressed. As it goes forwards, that compression is reversed. I guess in those cabs, movement of the cone is restricted due to this. So maybe the volume produced is less than in a ported or open cab, although with an open cab, a lot (maybe half) of the sound goes out the back. I'm looking for reasons why different cabs are produced, to make the most of that info. when I make this new cab.

Comment: I actually strongly prefer sealed enclosures. There are downsides to ports - phase coherence challenges and distortion caused by air turbulence are just the two biggest ones. The main advantage of ports is giving a smaller enclosure extended bass response that is not possible in a sealed enclosure of the same size. Ports are almost universal because they create a certain kind of value for the money: more bass at a lower price. Unfortunately, the "more bass" they provide is lower quality bass - it's poorly damped, uneven, and has greater THD compared with a sealed enclosure.

Comment: @Mazura Can you explain the popularity and reliability of the Marshall 4x12 cabinet (and the hundreds of near identical designs) for guitar amplification which is completely sealed? These cabinets are meant for gigging, sound great, last for decades, and as I mentioned, they have zero ports, vents, etc. They are completely sealed. Also I have a pair of Advent home stereo speakers that are completely sealed and were made in the 1970s. They sound great and are still going strong after about 50 years. "movement of the cone is restricted is not good for the cone." - **false**

Comment: @Mazura - you're adding a lot of confusion & little clarity to this debate.